# Stronger exponential bound

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Show that for $j \geq (e^2-1)n$ we have the following bound:

$$\left(1+ \frac{j}{n}\right)^{n}e^{-j} \leq e^{-j/2}$$

Motivation: This result allow us to conclude that if $u$ is a function that satisfies the heat equation, then $u$ is analytic.

*Proof*: I'm trying to use the condition over $j$, but I don't get closer to the result.

$$\ln\left(\left(1+ \frac{j}{n}\right)^{n}e^{-j}\right) = n \ln\left(1+\frac{j}{n}\right) - j \leq \frac{-j}{2}.$$

I need tho show the last inequality, and that is equivalent to show:

$$n\ln\left(1+\frac{j}{n}\right) \leq \frac{j}{2}$$

But I don't find the way to bound the logarithm with the hypothesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$ f(x)=n\ln\bigg(1+\frac xn\bigg)-\frac x2 $$
and then
$$ f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+\frac xn}-\frac 12=\frac{n-x}{2(n+x)}. $$
So if $x>n$, $f'(x)<0$ and hence $f(x)$ is decreasing. So for $j>(e^2-1)n$,
$$ f(j)<f((e^2-1)n).$$
Note
$$ f((e^2-1)n)=2n-\frac{(e^2-1)n}2=\frac n2(5-e^2)<0 $$
and hence
$$  n\ln\bigg(1+\frac jn\bigg)\le\frac j2. $$